# Pensavo che sia stato lui/ sapevo che è stato lui?

Tags: verbs, grammar

Va bene usare il congiuntivo passato/ passato prossimo come alternativa al congiuntivo trapassato/ trapassato prossimo?

A me sinceramente non suona bene, però magari è una mia impressione.

Grazie a tutti

Comment: “Pensavo” o “sapevo”? Da questo punto di vista si comportano in modo diverso.

Answer (score 3):

La forma corretta è:

Pensavo che fosse stato lui / Sapevo che era stato lui

Usando **'Pensavo'** esprimo una supposizione espressa nel passato.

Utilizzando **'Sapevo'** esprimo la conoscenza di un fatto maturata nel passato.

Comment: Quindi  è complementamente sbagliato dire "pensavo che sia stato lui" e "sapevo che è stato lui"?

Comment: Nella lingua parlata a volte si possono sentire e se utilizzate in modo attento quelle frasi possono dare sfumature interessanti, ma spesso non sono percepite come uso raffinato della lingua Italiana. Come linea generale per evitare errori è meglio non mescolare tempi verbali diversi nella stessa frase che se non utilizzati correttamente possono portare a fraintendimenti. Le forme corrette ad esempio sono 'Penso che sia stato Lui' e 'Pensavo che fosse stato Lui' . E' corretto anche 'Penso che è stato Lui' a significare che nel presente ho la convinzione che nel passato Lui ha compiuto l'azione